# ShellExecute sem Aviso de Segurança

Tags: delphi, windows

Como executar um aplicativo com o `ShellExecute` e impedir que o Windows emita o "Aviso de Segurança"?

Há algum parâmetro que possa ser enviado para evitar o aviso?
Já tentei aplicar alguns em pesquisas que fiz na web porém nenhum se mostrou satisfatório.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sim. E você terá que usar a [função `ShellExecuteEx`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762154(v=vs.85).aspx).

Você pode desativar temporariamente a variável de ambiente [`SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Do not perform a zone check. This flag allows `ShellExecuteEx` to
>   bypass zone checking put into place by [`IAttachmentExecute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb776297(v=vs.85).aspx).

Para usá-la, faça assim:

```
Uses
  ShellApi;
//...

function executarArquivo(const arquivo: string): LongBool;
Var
  SE: TShellExecuteInfo;
begin
  SE.cbSize := SizeOf(SE);
  SE.fMask := SEE_MASK_NOZONECHECKS;
  SE.lpFile := pchar(arquivo);
  SE.nShow := SW_SHOWNORMAL;
  //SE.lpVerb := 'runas'; // Para executar o programa como admin

  Result := ShellExecuteEx(@SE);
end;
```

Comment: Perfeito amigo!!  
Muito obrigado.